# How to convert path formats to use them whatever the platform or the module they came from?

Tags: python, path, format

I'm using

```
abspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

to get the folder of the current scipt that is excecuted which give me :

```
'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\Model_HIPP_ATN_Reu'
```

Then I'm using a `QFileDialog`to get a save file path which give me :

```
savefile : 'C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/Model_HIPP_ATN_Reu/PopsManager_auto/Model.py'
```

What I would like to do is find the relative path between those two paths with `path.relpath` So something like:

```
    savefile=savefile.replace('/','\\') 
    os.path.relpath(savefile,abspath)
```

which give me the correct folder path:

```
'PopsManager_auto/Model.py'
```

But my problem with that is if I get the savefile or the abspath on different system this code won't work because path formats are not the same. How can I have path in the same format whatever the platform and whatever the way I get paths (Qt or Os modules for instance)? I don't want use `.replace('/','\\')` because this will only work on Window, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to know: `os.path` is a shortcut to your system's specific `path` module, but you can still access other systems path modules by their names, ie `import ntpath, posixpath, macpath` (but I doubt you'll have a need for macpath - it's the pre OSX path system). You can use this to test what happens when switching from one system to another.

Also, "/" is a valid path sep for Windows, and lives as `ntpath.altsep` ( while `posixpath.altsep` and `macpath.altsep`  are `None`), and `ntpath` knows how to deal with both separators so you actually don't have to do any replacement on `abspath` before using `os.path.relpath()`:

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> abspath = "C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\Model_HIPP_ATN_Reu"
>>> savefile= 'C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/Model_HIPP_ATN_Reu/PopsManager_auto/Model.py'
>>> relative = ntpath.relpath(savefile, abspath)
>>> relative 
'PopsManager_auto\\Model.py'
```

*At this point I notice that I don't get the same result as you for the relative path (I get the above result with either py2.7.x and py3.4.3 - I don't have py3.6.x installed here). What exact python version are you actually using ?*

Now if you want to "normalize" your relative path, you can just test what the current `os.path.altsep` value is and if it's not `None`, use it for a replace:

```
>>> # Q&D hack to use `ntpath` as `os.path` on a posix system
>>> import os, ntpath; os.path = ntpath
>>> # now pretend we're on a nt system
>>> if os.path.altsep:
...     relative = relative.replace(os.path.sep, os.path.altsep)
... 
>>> relative
'PopsManager_auto/Model.py'
```

so now you have a relative path that is valid for both `posixpath` and `ntpath`.

When it comes to rebuild an absolute path from this relative path and a root directory path, all you have to do is to apply `os.path.normpath()` to both the root path and the relative path and then `os.path.join()` them:

```
>>> relative
'PopsManager_auto/Model.py'
>>> os.path.normpath(relative)
'PopsManager_auto\\Model.py'
>>> root = "C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\Model_HIPP_ATN_Reu"
>>> relative = os.path.normpath(relative)
>>> relative
'PopsManager_auto\\Model.py'
>>> os.path.join(root, relative)
'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\Model_HIPP_ATN_Reu\\PopsManager_auto\\Model.py'
```

Comment: OK I see. I didn't even test path.repath with mixed / and \\. Indeed that's working. So my bad about that. os.path.normpath will do the trick, so whatever the plateform I will load my file I will be able to convert the relative path to that platform. So thanks a lot. By the way, I'm using the 3.6.1 version of python.

Comment: So one main trick is that ntpath reads both forms, and then can write in its alternate form that is posixpath.  So something like `os.listdir(os.path.join(ntpath.normpath(r"./..\\.\\."),ntpath.normpath(r"..\.\.\.\\..").replace(ntpath.sep,ntpath.altsep)))` works for both.